# Exploring the Limiting Behavior of $(n + 1)^n$ in Base $ n $ as $ n $ Approaches Infinity

Tags: limits, binomial-theorem, eulers-number-e

Hello Math Stack Exchange Community,

I've been investigating an [interesting pattern](https://oeis.org/A259080) in the polynomial expansion of $(n + 1)^n$ when expressed in base $ n $, specifically the emergence of a consistent pattern where the leftmost digit is '2', and the rightmost two digits are '01', with the middle coefficients varying. This is observed for finite values of $ n $. My question revolves around understanding the behavior of this expression as $ n $ approaches infinity.

We know the following:

1. $ n^n (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = (n + 1)^n $
2. $n^n$ shifts the decimal point of $ (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n $ $n$-many places to the right in base $n$, leaving the digits in tact
3. $(n + 1)^n$ in base $n$ is ($n + 1$)-many digits (i.e. coefficients) long for all $n > 2$
4. As $ n $ grows larger, $ (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n $ approaches Euler's number $ e $
5. The constant $2 \ldots 01_n$ pattern reflects the symmetric $1_n$ and $10_n$ that bookend the expansion (as a consequence of the binomial theorem), and the carries of the "$1$" of $10_n$

In the limit as $ n $ approaches infinity, how can we interpret this pattern of $2 \ldots 01_n$ in base $ n $ in relation to $ e $? Is there a meaningful way to discuss the concept of $ e $ in an "infinite base" system, or does the notion become abstract or theoretical?

There is also an apparent pattern in the three terminal digits, of "$101$" for odd $ n $ and $ 
m + $ "$01$", where $ m = \frac{n}{2} + 1 $ for even $ n $. Can we prove this holds?

I am also curious about any relevant mathematical literature or research that delves into this area. So far, my searches have not yielded much, and I would greatly appreciate any insights or references that could guide my understanding of this phenomenon.

Here is the Mathematica code for any one interested:

```
Table[{n, IntegerDigits[(n + 1)^n, n]}, {n, 2, 100}]
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the question "Can we prove [the '101'] pattern holds?", here is a visual proof in Wolfram Language. The triangular numbers can be defined as the sequence of (*duplicate*) successive odd numbers, where each odd number is scaled by $n$ or $n + 1$ depending on its parity in the sequence. These are listed in the last two columns. The "$1$" from the $n$'s place of $10_{n}$ at $n \choose n - 1$ gets carried to the ones place of the triangular number, $n \choose n - 2$, which either holds a "$0$" (yielding the leading "$1$" of $101$ for odd $n$) or the $\frac{n}{2}$th natural number (which gets incremented to yield the pattern $m+$"$01$", where $m = \frac{n}{2} + 1$) for even $n$. Note that $n \choose n - 2$ is the $(n - 1)$th triangular number, not the $n$th. To simplify discussion, I'm considering the reflection of the triangular number in the binomial expansion, as $\binom{n}{k}$ is symmetric and equal to $ \binom{n}{n-k} $. Many thanks to the commenters for your guidance and insights:

```
(*Define the table*)
table = Table[{n,(*Column 1:n*)2 n + 1,(*Column 2:
    2n+1*)(2 n + 1)*n,(*Column 3:(2n+1)*
    n*)(2 n + 1)*(n + 1),(*Column 4:(2n+1)*(n+1)*)
    BaseForm[(2 n + 1)*n, 2 n],(*Column 5:(2n+1)*n in base (2n+1)*)
    BaseForm[(2 n + 1)*(n + 1), 
     2 n + 1] (*Column 6:(2n+1)*(n+1) in base 2n*)}, {n, 0, 
    36} (*Adjust the range as needed*)];

(*Label and display the table*)
labels = {"n", "2n + 1", "(2n+ 1) * n", "(2n+ 1) * (n+1)", 
   "(2n+ 1) * n in base 2n", "(2n+ 1) * (n+1) in base (2n+1)"};
labeledTable = Prepend[table, labels];

(*Display the table,for example,using Grid for formatting*)
Grid[labeledTable, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Visual Proof]

Answer (score 1):

The $2$ is explained as follows: As $n$ gets large, the first digits of $(n+1)^n\sim en^n$ will approach those corresponding to $2.71828...$ base ten. In the varying base $n$ the $.71728...$ part has varying digits, but the integer $2$ ahead of the decimal point remains just $2$ in any base $\ge 3$.

You should also see some regularity in the second digit base $n$; plot it as a function of $n$ for let's say $n$ equal to powers of $2$ up to $2^{16}$ and note what happens (choosing these bases allows you to work with just the binary representation). Can you explain the apparent asymptotic behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the insights. My focus in this comment is on the binomial expansion's left-hand side. Analyzing up to `n = 10000` shows linear progression, yet plotting `n = 2^z` to `z = 16` does hint at asymptotic behavior. Discussing with Robert Israel, I noted triangular numbers in base `n`: `00_1`, `01_2`, `10_3`, `12_4`, `20_5`, etc. The 'n's place' of these coefficients, added to the binomial expansion's second coefficient's (`10_n`'s) '0' yields natural numbers in pairs, and potentially altered by carries. Your point on these modifications suggesting an asymptotic distribution is intriguing.

Answer (score 1):

The final $0$ and $1$ is because the binomial theorem gives you

$$ (n+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} n^k $$
The terms for $k \ge 2$ are all divisible by $n^2$, the $k=1$ term is $n^2$ because ${n \choose 1} = n$, and the $k=0$ term is $1$.

BTW, since the $k=2$ term is $n^3 (n-1)/2$, when $n$ is odd the third-last digit is $1$, while if $n$ is even it is $n/2 + 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was very helpful. Your formula for the k = 2 term shows up as n^3 (n - 1)/2, when the formula is n (n - 1)/2, but this helps me understand the pattern for odd numbers. For odd n, (n - 1)/2 is the index of n in the odd integer series, which will result in the natural number series being listed in the third to last position across odd n. Still studying your explanation for the 1 for even n. Also, would love to know your thoughts on the implication for n in the limit as n -> ∞

Comment: Corrections. It's true that for odd n, (n - 1)/2 is the index of n in the odd numbers, and n * (n - 1)/2 is the natural numbers in the n's place plus a '0' in the ones place, but all that can be relied upon is the 0 being left by the carry of the natural number. The '1' of 10_n in the penultimate position then fills the 0, and that gives us the leading '1' of 101 for odd n. Next comment will explain the case for even n.

Comment: A striking pattern in the third to last position occurs for even n. The pattern is, beginning with n = 2: 01_2, 12_4, 23_6, 34_8, 45_10, and so on. The one's place of these numbers increment the natural numbers (so does the n's place, but that get's carried and the information is apparently lost), and so (contrary to my first response to this comment) this explains why the natural number series is listed in the third to last position across all *even* n. A proof of the 01, 12, 23, 34... pattern would be nice. Also, there still remains the main question about e.

Comment: It should be noted that the one's place of the third to last number, in the case of even n, is incremented by the 1 that carries from the penultimate 10_n, effectively shifting the series.

Comment: I don't understand.  For $n = 4$, the third-last digit of $(4+1)^4$ in base $4$ is $3 = 4/2 + 1$.  For $n=6$, the third-last digit of $(6+1)^6$ in base $6$ is $4 = 6/2 + 1$.  For $n = 8$. the third-last digit of $(8+1)^8$ is $5 = 8/2 + 1$.  And so on.

Comment: The formula is actually that of the Triangular numbers: n * (n - 1)/2, so the expansion is (n + 1) ^ n = 1_n + 10_n + T(n - 1)_n + .... + T(n - 1)_n + 10_n + 1_n, where T(n - 1) is the (n - 1)th triangular number. I'm focusing on the pattern reflected by the simplex numbers in this context and not delving into the specific formula for the actual simplex number on the right-hand side of the expansion to keep the discussion straightforward...

Comment: ...Adding from right-to-left, no carries for ones place, but for 10_n (n's place), we carry the "1" of 10_n, which leaves a 0 in the n's place. Now to your comment, e.g. T(n - 1)_n = 34_n for n = 8, and when we add the carried "1" the result is 35_n in the "triangles" place. Carrying the "3" of 35 (to the tetrahedra place) leaves a 5 in the triangles place. Keep carrying until you reach the initial digit (which becomes the 2 of the integral part when n^n is factored out).